# PYQT5 - Link to page in exported pdf

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene

I am creating an application to draw instructions for a user.
The one creating the instructions can add multiple pages and then export them to .pdf.
All of that works fine, except that I can't seem to get links between the different pages.

I want to add an initial page that will show all the pages and have links to them (table of contents) and add a button on each page that will link to the next / previous page.

What I currently have to export is this:

```
def __export_page_to_pdf(self):
    """ Export the current pages to pdf. . """
    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName("instructions.pdf")
    printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPageSize(self.__page.size, QtGui.QPageSize.Point))

    painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
    for page_number in range(self.__page_count):
        self.set_page(page_number)

        x_scale = self.__page.size.width() / self.width()
        y_scale = self.__page.size.height() / self.height()
        painter.scale(x_scale, y_scale)

        self.render(painter)

        if page_number < self.__page_count - 1:
            painter.resetTransform()
            printer.newPage()
    painter.end()
```

The `self.set_page(page_number)` changes the current page so the one requested can be rendered. `self.set_page(0)` contains the page with the TOC.

All pages are shown in a QGraphicsScene.
I'd appreciate any hints on how to create the links between these pages.

Comment: Using QPrinter that way will just create a series of images (one for each page) and store them in a pdf, so the resulting file has very little internal structure. You'd  need to print from a QTextDocument to get links, but there are a number of bugs in Qt5's pdf support that mean internal links don't work properly - see: [QTBUG-83458](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83458). This means you'll need to use a third-party pdf library to get the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the response by [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) I investigated 3rd party software.
The functionality that I seek is possible with the [PyMuPdf](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) package.
The steps to take are to place text / images in the original pdf. Then using the PyMuPdf package use a snippet similar to this one:

```
import fitz # This is the import name for PyMuPdf. Use pip install PyMuPdf to install
doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")
new_link = {
    "kind": 1, # I am unsure what this does but it is required.
    "from": fitz.Rect(32, 504, 50, 534), # Locaton of the link.
    "page": 1, # The page to link to.
    "to": fitz.Point(0, 0), # The location on the new page.
    "zoom": 0 # The zoom of the new page.
}

for i in range(doc.page_count): # Use this method of iterating to prevent pages not being edited.
    page_link = dict(new_link) # Copy template.
    page_link["page"] = i + 1 # Update page to link to.
    doc[i].insert_link(page_link) # Insert the link.
```